# Preg_replace и знак доллара

Tags: php

В цикле формируется значение цен, примерно так:

```
$n=0;
$pricesArray - массив цен
$cell = '<td><input type="text" class="input-text" name="{{cellname}}" value="{{val}}"></td>'
for($i=0; $i < $countColumns; $i++){
    //$pricesArray[$n]['prices'][$i] - значение примерно такое 15.09
    $value = sprintf("%01.2f", $pricesArray[$n]['prices'][$i]);
    $value = '$' . $value;
    $cell = preg_replace('/{{val}}/',$value, $cell);
}
```

в результате на каждой итерации вместо значения `{{val}}` должно быть такое:  `$15.09`, а получается такое: `.09`
Как правильно добавлять знак доллара к цене?

Comment: \$ Знак доллара.

Comment: https://puzzleweb.ru/php/03_datatypes3.php

Comment: А смысл `preg_replace` здесь в чем?

Comment: @Bloom,  $value = '\$' . $value; такой вариант не работает, echo $value выводит: \$15.09, но после preg_replace вырезается значение до точки:  цена = .09, а должна быть 15.09

Comment: у тя регулярка режет

Comment: @u_mulder, `preg_replace` чтобы вырезать значение `{{val}}` это значение как шаблон

Comment: @Bloom, а как правильно нужно?

Comment: Тут нет никакого регулярного выражения, достаточно `str_replace`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Шаблон `{{val}}` не содержит никаких регулярных выражений, поэтому использование `preg_replace` бессмысленно, достаточно сделать:

```
$cell = str_replace('{{val}}', $value, $cell);
```

Что касается `preg_replace` то выражение `$15` в замене считается получением 15-й группы из совпадения. Естественно у вас такой нет, поэтому надо экранировать `$`:

```
$value = '\$' . $value;
$cell = preg_replace('/{{val}}/', $value, $cell);
```

Пример с обоими вариантами - https://3v4l.org/Er3l9

Answer (score 2):

Проблема в использовании preg_replace.
Это не только утяжеляет код, но и приводит к такой ошибке.
Нужно заменить

```
$cell = preg_replace('/{{val}}/',$value, $cell);
```

на

```
$cell = str_replace('{{val}}',$value, $cell);
```